# gRPC client having lots of issues and not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc

I started using gRPC with Visual Studio 2022 and never saw so many issues as now.

1. When I wanted to create an additional Proto file I got the error saying that I need to specify the language. That's weird, because I selected the proper option which is designed for C#. So it never worked and I simply had to copy default greeter file.
2. I created the console app which uses this default greeter service and it even worked. But I added the additional proto and created another fairy simple service and it did not want to compile it referring to some missing types of something. I can't remember the exact error message but I resolved it only by reducing the grpc.* package version to 2.27.I found this answer by googling and I find it weird that Microsoft releases something what does not work in the most simple case scenario.
3. I decided to test my new test grpc service and created the client:

   ```
    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
    var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
    var reply = await client.MySimpleMethodAsync(new MyRequest { Id = 123 });
    Console.WriteLine(reply.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
   ```

The MySimpleMethodAsync method is very simple, it just reads the record from the DB using Dapper, nothing special.
Surprisingly there was no compilation error, but when I tried to run it (along with the server app) I got the exception on the line var reply = await client.MySimpleMethodAsync, saying Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unimplemented, Detail="Service is unimplemented.")'

I don't understand why it says so. The service is implemented, it's compilable! Googling did not help but I found that other people are having the same issue too.

4. Eventually I found that if I modify the grpc service and for some reason it does not like it and then I rollback the changes, it's not compilable anymore! I clearn solution, rebuild it - nothing helps! The only thing which helps is addting the brand new project and copy pasting the previous "stable" code.
   I've never seen such the ...technology that never works!

Anyway, now the most important issue for me is #3 , why it says the service is not implemented?

Comment: "I got the error saying that I need to specify the language" - where exactly did you get that? we can't see your screen; was this a build error? if so: did you look at the csproj to see how the pre-existing working file was configured, vs how your new file?

Comment: "I found this answer by googling and I find it weird that Microsoft releases something what does not work in the most simple case scenario." - note: the `Grpc.*` packages *aren't released by Microsoft* - they're by Google; when using them, is expected that the code-gen tooling and the library tooling will be using the same version; did you check whether the library version and codegen version (again, in the csproj) were matching?

Comment: "The service is implemented, it's compilable!" - that isn't quite the same thing; we can see your client code, but can we see your server code? did you leave it as `throw new NotImplementedException()`? did you even register the service at the server setup?

Comment: BTW: if you're finding all this confusing and awkward, and if you're working .NET to .NET: you might find it easier to just *skip the .proto completely*, and work "code first" - here's a much simpler way of using gRPC in .NET: https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted

Comment: Its now March 2022 and I am running into the exact same issues you detailed above. gRPC on Visual Studio appears to have a lot of stability issues.